# Number Range diff

Tags: sql-server

I have a question, I have a sample data shown below: my question is I want to calculate the difference between second row starting number (150) to first row ending number (100).
Can any one please help me? This answer will reduce some manual work what I'm doing daily.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for something other than `150-100=50` you'll need to explain better what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, I have a list of serial numbers shipment which has starting and ending number for each bach. Some times they are missing to send us some batch information. so I'm trying to find a way to automate the process so the vendor will know about the missing batch information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  Model nvarchar(5),
  StartingNo int,
  EndingNo int
);

insert into MyTable (Model, StartingNo, EndingNo) values
('X', 1, 100),
('X', 150, 200),
('Y', 10, 30),
('Y', 1, 5);
```

**Solution 1**

This solution uses an [outer apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?#using-apply) to fetch the previous row.

```
select  t1.*,
        t3.EndingNo as PreviousEndingNo,
        t1.StartingNo - t3.EndingNo as Diff
from MyTable t1
outer apply (   select top 1 t2.EndingNo            -- first row...
                from MyTable t2
                where t2.Model = t1.Model           -- ... with same model
                  and t2.StartingNo < t1.StartingNo -- ... that comes before current row
                order by t2.StartingNo desc ) t3    -- ... when sorting on start number
order by t1.Model, t1.StartingNo;
```

**Solution 2**

This solution uses the [lag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) function to fetch the previous row.

```
select  t1.*,
        lag(t1.EndingNo) over(partition by t1.Model order by t1.StartingNo) as PreviousEndingNo,
        t1.StartingNo - lag(t1.EndingNo) over(partition by t1.Model order by t1.StartingNo) as Diff
from MyTable t1
order by t1.Model, t1.StartingNo;
```

**Result**

```
Model StartingNo  EndingNo    PreviousEndingNo Diff
----- ----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------
X     1           100         NULL             NULL
X     150         200         100              50
Y     1           5           NULL             NULL
Y     10          30          5                5
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cca0651c9cb8a343286d559766c4630d) to see everything in action.

Comment: Hello Sander, is there any possibility of implementing the above logic with out using outer apply?

Comment: There are often multiple ways to achieve the same solution in T-SQL (with varying performance). Answer updated with a second solution that does not use `outer apply`.

Comment: Thanks Sander, I figured out a way with the help of CtE and row number. I got the required answer. Thanks for your timely and response.